# How to start the finite difference method on this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

I have to find the numerical solutions for the boundary value problem through matlab,

---

$2yy\prime\prime -(y\prime)^{2} + 4y^{2} = 0,   \quad  y(\pi/6) = 1/4, \quad y(\pi/2) = 1. $

---

It took so much time to how to start, I tried $dy/dx = u$ but failed...

Can anybody help??

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022144/solve-boundary-value-problem-for-y-y-exy-fx/2022149#2022149

Comment: I think that is little bit different from my problem, can you explain it more??

Answer (score 1):

If the words "difference method" are part of your task description, it would seem that you are expected to directly insert
$$
y'(t)=\frac{y(t+h)-y(t-h)}{2h},\qquad y''=\frac{y(t+h)-2y(t)+y(t-h)}{h^2}
$$
to get
$$
2y(t)(y(t+h)-2y(t)+y(t-h))-\frac14(y(t+h)-y(t-h))^2+4h^2y(t)^2=0
$$
which is a quadratic equation for $y(t+h)$.

---

Otherwise

```
function dz=prime(t,z)
     y=z(1), dy=z(2)
     dz = [ dy; (dy^2-4*y^2)/(2*y) ]
```

is a variant of the function to put into the BVP solver.

---

If you want to go Newton on your equation, compute the directional derivative in direction $v$ as
$$
2yv''+2y''v-2y'v'+8yv=0
$$

This works in Scilab, a close cousin of Matlab

```
function dz=prime(t,z)
     y=z(1), dy=z(2), v=z(3), dv=z(4)
     d2y = (dy^2-4*y^2)/(2*y);
     d2v = (dy*dv-4*y*v-d2y*v)/(y)
     dz = [ dy; d2y; dv; d2v ]
endfunction

Pi=4*atan(1)
t0 = Pi/6
y0 = 1/4
tf = Pi/2
yf = 1
a=1
dy0=1
while abs(a)>1e-14
    z0 = [y0; dy0; 0; 1]
    T = [tf]
    Z = ode(z0, t0, T, prime )
    n=length(T); n=n(1)
    a = (yf-Z(1,n))/Z(3,n)
    dy0=dy0+a
    disp([dy0,a])
end

T = linspace(t0,tf,301)
Z = ode(z0, t0, T, prime )
clf()
plot(T,Z(1,:),T,sin(T).^2)
```

Comment: I get the idea of the finite difference method, and understand how you made the equation as a quadratic equation, but now I cannot reach to the matlab code. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question and explain in more detail the task description. Are you expected to implement your own solver using only the basic fundamentals of the matlab language, and if yes, what is the method or basic idea that is to be implemented. Or, at the other end of the possibilities, is it that you have to find the shortest solution using the full power of matlab?

Comment: My bad Actually I found the way If I set $z= \sqrt{y}$ it makes a lot easier

Comment: Yes about $y=z^2$, I put a hint i the last line of the code that expands on the hint given by the particular form of the boundary values...